# moderncv user variable in section

Tags: moderncv

How can I use a variable (e.g. a first name) in `\cvitem`?

```
\firstname{Firstname}
  \begin{document}       
  \makecvtitle % Print the CV title
  \section{Personal Data}
  \cvitem{}{\firstname}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `\meaning\firstname`, you'll see that it just means

```
\def\@firstname{#1}
```

To get the functionality you want, you'll have to say

```
\firstname{Firstname}
  \begin{document}       
  \makecvtitle % Print the CV title
  \section{Personal Data}
  \cvitem{}{\makeatletter\@firstname\makeatother}
```

(Remembering, of course, that you can make a macro to do the dirty work for you if you plan to do this a lot: `\makeatletter\newcommand\myfirstname{\@firstname}\makeatother`.)

Comment: yes i saw my mistake, but if i use
  \cvitem{}{\makeatletter\@firstname\makeatother}

There are several problems at this line:
 -Missing } inserted. ...tem{}{\makeatletter\@firstname\makeatother} (followed by: )
 -You can't use `\spacefactor' in internal vertical mode. ...tem{}{\makeatletter\@firstname\makeatother} (followed by: )
 -Extra }, or forgotten $. ...tem{}{\makeatletter\@firstname\makeatother} (followed by: )
 -Missing $ inserted. ...tem{}{\makeatletter\@firstname\makeatother} (followed by: )

Comment: ok declared a new command
\newcommand*{\usefirstname}{\@firstname}

Comment: Did this fix your issue?  Don't forget you can 'accept' this answer to mark your issue as resolved :) (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852))